# Yii2: ¿cómo conectar frontend y backend de diferentes servidores con una API?

Tags: ajax, api, url, yii2, localhost

Hice mi primera API con el [tutorial oficial](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/es/rest-quick-start) de Yii2. Funciona perfecto con Postman (con los métodos GET y POST), pero lo que necesitaba es que mi frontend envíe datos a mi backend (en formato JSON) y ambos están en diferentes servidores.

Hice algo similar con AJAX y jQuery en otro proyecto para actualizar una lista de empleados en tiempo real sin tener que recargar toda la página. Algo así, bastante simplificado:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/empleados/empleados?idEmpleado=123",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
    },
    error: function(err) {              
        console.log("Error con empleados: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Es decir, tengo mi formulario de la vista que envía los datos al controlador y luego el controlador los guarda en mi base de datos.

Pero estoy muy confundido: ¿Debo usar AJAX? Si no uso ¿AJAX cómo uso la API con una URL en el backend y otra URL en el frontend?

Cualquier ayuda o link a un tutorial me resultará más que genial.

Comment: Yo lo considero como dos aplicaciones distintas. Así que realmente tú tienes una aplicación(frontend) que tiene sus rutas, e internamente llama a otra app externa (API/backend) para obtener datos o realizar acciones... No veo problema en que uses AJAX u otro método, incluso podrías hacer una app de tipo terminal de consola que llame al backend enviando Json...

Comment: ¡Genial! ¿Pero en qué parte de mi vista escribo la URL del servidor backend sin usar AJAX?

Comment: No sería en la vista. Sería más bien en un controlador o mejor aún en un servicio.

Comment: ¿Un servicio? ¿Por ejemplo? Gracias!